# SD card supports ReadyBoost in USB adaptor but not in SD card reader. How to fix?

Tags: sd-card, readyboost

When I insert an SD card into the SD reader, I am not offered the ReadyBoost tab in the drive properties section. When I put the card into a USB adaptor and plug it into the USB slot, ReadyBoost is offered and works fine.

How can I get the card reader to play with ReadyBoost?

Windows 7 on a Dell Latitude.

Thanks.

Comment: ReadyBoost is only offered to USB media, if your SD Reader isn't a USB device, SD card wouldn't fullfill that first requirement.  By using a USB Reader that is fulfilled.

Comment: My other thought is that although your SD card meets the read/write requirements, the SD reader itself may not have the specs to meet the minimum requirements. You can check to see if your SD card reader is USB based by looking at Control Panel > System > 
Device Manager. On my Dell Latitude it is its own subsystem, so I'm thinking @Ramhound is likely correct with the USB requirement for ReadyBoost: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff356869.aspx

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions - in following up on your answers I found a solution which worked for me, posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: 
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/275037-32-card-ready-boost

> apparently Class 4 sdmc cards will work if you have a class 10 there is a hack to make that work, open regedit, START BUTTON Search box at
>   bottom enter REGEDIT then this path...
>
> HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE, SOFTWARE, Microsoft, Windows NT, current version,
>   EDMgmt
>
> you will see several SDMC cards that begin with ?? (2 question marks)
>   right click on all of these and delete the entries.
>
> restart windows wirh SDMC card in slot now re open regedit and fololow
>   same path
>
> HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE,SOFTWARE,Microsoft,Windows NT,current
>   version,EDMgmt there will be a new entry at the top of the list with 2
>   ?, this is your card, select it then select device ststus and change
>   the entry from 1 to 2  close regedit now you have a class 10 card
>   running capable of READYBOOST
>
> apparently Class 4 sdmc cards will work if you have a class 10 there
>   is a hack to make that work, open regedit, START BUTTON Search box at
>   bottom enter REGEDIT then this path...
>
> HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE, SOFTWARE, Microsoft, Windows NT, current version,
>   EDMgmt
>
> you will see several SDMC cards that begin with ?? (2 question marks)
>   right click on all of these and delete the entries.
>
> restart windows wirh SDMC card in slot now re open regedit and fololow
>   same path
>
> HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE,SOFTWARE,Microsoft,Windows NT,current
>   version,EDMgmt there will be a new entry at the top of the list with 2
>   ?, this is your card, select it then select device ststus and change
>   the entry from 1 to 2  close regedit now you have a class 10 card
>   running capable of READYBOOST

Had SCSI instead of SDMC and edited from 12 to 2 instead of 1 to 2, but worked like a charm.